# JQuery: Convert GET URL to POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, get

what's the easiest way to convert a GET URL string to POST in jQuery?

e.g. I want the params of a link

```
    <a href="/somepage?x=1&amp;y=3" id="postlink">link</a>
```

to be submitted as POST onclick if javascript is activated. No AJAX, just normal form submitting.

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Hannes.

Comment: be specific about your requirement.. can't figure out what's your prooblem ??

Comment: found this might be useful http://tomengineering.tripod.com/gettopost.html

Comment: The "problem" is I want data only submitted via POST if javascript is activated. I figure I could add a hidden form based on the URL to the DOM on the fly. But is there an easier or more elegant way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just write this code, check please, may be it helpful http://jsfiddle.net/AEwxt/

```
$('#postlink').click(function() {
    var p = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
    var action = p[0];
    var params = p[1].split('&');
    var form = $(document.createElement('form')).attr('action', action).attr('method','post');
    $('body').append(form);
    for (var i in params) {
        var tmp= params[i].split('=');
        var key = tmp[0], value = tmp[1];
        $(document.createElement('input')).attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', key).attr('value', value).appendTo(form);
    }
    $(form).submit();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why are you repeating ".attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', key).attr('value', value)"? This triggers an IE8 bug in jQuery and seems to be a typo :)

Answer (score 3):

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/w5WA6/

```
function getUrlVars(_url)
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = _url.slice(_url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];

    }

    return vars;
}

var arVars = getUrlVars($("#test").attr("href"));
for(var i=0;i<arVars.length;i++){
    //put var in input for submition you can change type by `hidden`
    $("#myForm").append("<input type='text' value='"+arVars[arVars[i]]+"' name='"+arVars[i]+"'/>");
}
​
```

Answer (score 2):

Modified Sergey's code a little, so that when the user 'hovers' on the link, it does not display the get request.

Link:

```
<a href="#" postURL="/tpl/schRosterSearchSubmit.do?searchReci.uniqueId=&searchReci.studentId=&searchReci.schoolId=3205&searchReci.name.firstName=&searchReci.name.lastName=&searchReci.gender=&searchReci.rdobDay=&searchReci.rdobMonth=&searchReci.rdobYear=&searchReci.rssn1=&searchReci.rssn2=&searchReci.rssn3=&searchReci.phoneNumber=&searchReci.citzOrResAlien=&searchReci.country.isoCountryCode=&searchReci.address.street1=&searchReci.address.street2=&searchReci.address.city=&searchReci.address.state=&searchReci.address.zip=&searchReci.address.zipExt=&searchReci.parentN.firstName=&searchReci.parentN.lastName=&searchReci.parentEmail=&searchReci.parentMAddr.street1=&searchReci.parentMAddr.street2=&searchReci.parentMAddr.city=&searchReci.parentMAddr.state=&searchReci.parentMAddr.zip=&searchReci.parentMAddr.zipExt=&searchReci.parentPAddr.street1=&searchReci.parentPAddr.street2=&searchReci.parentPAddr.city=&searchReci.parentPAddr.state=&searchReci.parentPAddr.zip=&searchReci.parentPAddr.zipExt=&searchReci.pdobDay=&searchReci.pdobMonth=&searchReci.pdobYear=&searchReci.pssn1=&searchReci.pssn2=&searchReci.pssn3=&searchReci.parentCitzOrResAlien=&searchReci.parentCountry.isoCountryCode=&searchReci.addrUpdInd=&searchReci.inactiveDtDay=&searchReci.inactiveDtMonth=&searchReci.inactiveDtYear=&searchReci.ncoaUpdInd=&searchReci.badAddrInd=&branding=upromise&acct=XXXX&schRosterPager.offset=50" class="rnavLink">2nd Page results</a>
```

Converting to POST onclick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rnavLink').click(function() {
        var p = $(this).attr('postURL').split('?');
        var action = p[0];
        var params = p[1].split('&');
        var form = $('<form/>', {action:action, method:'post'}).appendTo('body');
        for (var i in params) {
            var tmp = params[i].split('=');
            var key = tmp[0], value = tmp[1];
            $('<input/>', {type:'hidden', name:key, value:value}).appendTo(form);
        }
        $(form).submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can send form input using HTML
    <form method="POST">

While I'm not entirely sure of the rationale behind this, if you must enforce the javascript part, simply surround it the form with <form method="GET"> with a <noscript> tag.